# Calling a method from other class

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

I have 2 classes named as:

- **InputFunctionView**
- **BaseTemplateView**

I created a method **cancelStickerPreviewButtonPressed** inside **InputFunctionView** class that I want to call it from **BaseTemplateView** class.

Here is my code:

***InputFunctionView.h***

```
#import <...>

@class InputFunctionView;
@protocol InputFunctionViewDelegate <NSObject>
 ...
@end

@interface InputFunctionView : UIView <...> {

}


- (void)cancelStickerPreviewButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

***InputFunctionView.m***

```
- (void)cancelStickerPreviewButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    // This part doesn't work when called from other class. Why?
    NSLog(@"cancel sticker preview");
    [self.previewCancelButton removeFromSuperview];
    [_stickerPreviewView removeFromSuperview];

}
```

***BaseTemplateView.h***

```
    #import <...>

    @interface BaseTemplateView : UIViewController


    @end
```

***BaseTemplateView.m***

```
#import "InputFunctionView.h"

- (void) MethodA {

InputFunctionView *IFV = [[InputFunctionView alloc]init];
[IFV cancelStickerPreviewButtonPressed:nil];

}
```

My question is why in **InputFunctionView.m** method **cancelStickerPreviewButtonPressed** this below part doesn't work? previewCancelButton and stickerPreviewView are supposed to be removed from its superview but no. What am I missing?

```
// This part doesn't work when called from other class. Why?
    NSLog(@"cancel sticker preview");
    [self.previewCancelButton removeFromSuperview];
    [_stickerPreviewView removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Can't see error...What error you getting?

Comment: When I type those lines there's no auto fill so that means something's wrong

Comment: can you post your error what you are getting here in both line & regarding autofill some time its not working in XCode.

Comment: as Dhansesh said: codehinting in Xcode sometimes breaks, could that be your case? Clearing derived data might help if it is so...

Comment: I've got error in this line saying **No visible @interface for 'InputFunctionView' declares the selector 'cancelStickerPreviewButtonPressed'**

Comment: Now I got it through by using `[IFV cancelStickerPreviewButtonPressed:nil];` as it must match both method name and parameter. Now the method cancelStickerPreviewButtonPressed was called but `[self.previewCancelButton removeFromSuperview];
    [_stickerPreviewView removeFromSuperview];` don't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Might be help you using `Class` method

In `InputFunctionView.h`

```
+(void)yourMethod;
```

In `InputFunctionView.m`

```
+(void)yourMethod
{
    NSLog(@"Your method called");
}
```

In `BaseTemplateView.h`

```
- (void) MethodA {  // Need to import InputFunctionView.h 

     [InputFunctionView yourMethod];
}
```

Happy coding...